# Error when referencing a inside a function without using `global` keyword in python

Tags: python, global, local

Why does the following code raise an `UnboundedLocalError`:

```py
n = 0
def foo():
    n = n + 1
    print(n)
foo()
foo()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 5, in <module>
    foo()
  File "foo.py", line 3, in foo
    n = n + 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

While the following code works:

```py
n = 0
def foo():
    print(n)
foo()
foo()
```

Output:

```
0
0
```

It seems to me that given the behavior of the second snippet, the first snippet should use the value of the *global* `n` to calculate `n+1` and assign it to a new *local* `n`, and print it. Thus, I would expect the output to be two `1`s. Why does this not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you write `n = ...`, `n` becomes a *local* variable for the entire function scope. To make the name `n` refer to the *global* variable, you must use the `global` statement.

In the second example, there is no assignment to `n`, so `n` is undefined. It's a *free* variable, and its value will be taken from the closest enclosing scope where `n` *is* defined.